# VSTO Outlook Addin Email Sender Name

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a VSTO Outlook 2013 addin that reads properties from CurrentItem when the read mail window is open.  When I get the property Sender I always get system.__comobject  Why does it keep returning this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869056.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property returns an [AddressEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869306.aspx) object that corresponds to the user of the account from which the MailItem is sent.

Comment: Ah that makes sense as to why I'm getting that value back.  What is the proper way to access the string representing the display name of the sender then?  AddressEntry.Name doesn't seem to be correct.  If it is, then what is the difference between AddressEntry.Address and MailItem.SenderEmailAddress?

Comment: Both ways are acceptable (work the same way). You may find the [GetContacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff862409.aspx) method of the AddressEntry class helpful. It returns a ContactItem object that represents the AddressEntry, if the AddressEntry corresponds to a contact in an Outlook Contacts Address Book (CAB).

Answer (score 1):

```
//if it is a regular mail or a Meeting mail
var senderName = mail.Sendername;

//if it is a task mail
var senderName = mail.Owner;
```

Wish can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace oApp1 = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

oApp1.CurrentUser.Name;

Comment: An explanation of what you have done, and the issue you are facing would be great. Just posting some code could not help to understand your issue.